# both parameters are default?

Tags: c++

```
    void method( double code = 0, CQueue* = NULL).
```

I have this method defined in ".h" file . In the .cpp file I assign the values of code in ont method( I want the queue to be a null here) and  queue is assigned a null in another method ( code has to be a 0 here) 
 Having both the parameters a default type is it valid in c++?
What can be an alternative way?

Comment: Without specifying the type of queue it is not valid C++ code!

Comment: @Burkhard: Well, `queue` could be a type itself, constructible from `NULL`, and the code would be fine.

Comment: Thanks GManNickG. You are of course right!

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly valid. It means that `method();` is identical to `method(0, NULL);`, and `method(x);` is the same as `method(x, NULL);` and finally `method(x, y);` is just itself.

To pass a queue alone, you'll need to overload the function (i.e. have another function with the same name but different parameters). Something like this:

```
void method(queue q)
{
    method(some-default-value, q);
}
```

Comment: That you cannot do. You'll have to specify the `code` value or you'll have to create a separate version of the function that is `void method(queue);`.

Comment: @user1563551 You cannot specify the second argument but not the first. You can specify no arguments, the first, or both.

Comment: Don't think you can just specify the 2nd argument without explicitly setting the first -- unless you also have method(queue) overloaded.

Comment: alright got it! I cannot have method(queue2); but I can have method(0, queue2) right?

Comment: @user1563551: You can. You can also use the function overload I edited into my answer to avoid having to write the `0, ` every time if you want `0` to be the default case there.

Comment: I donot want to overload the method. Inspite of that I still get the error when : method(cqueue); is passed?

Comment: @user1563551: Why don't you want to overload it? If you look, I'm just calling the function again anyway, just supplying the correct default. Anyway, if you don't want to overload it, you'll have to write `method(0, cqueue);` then.

Comment: but according to my knowledge,http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/   a method can take all its parameters to be  default parameters , why is it that method(queue2); be an error?

Comment: @user1563551: Because if you give it only one argument (just `queue2`), it's always assumed to be the first argument (a `double`). Since `queue2` is not a `double`, it does not compile. Arguments must always come in the same order as the parameters of the function definition. Really, though, this is almost a new question at this point.

Comment: even if I had passed, method (2.3); I get an error. It is in the order in which it is originally defined?

Comment: @user1563551: That looks like a different issue, you'd have to post what the actual error is, probably in a new question about it. This comment thread is way too long; it's bugging me to use chat instead but you don't have enough rep for that. I suggest you read up on C++ functions and how the compiler chooses which function to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid.

One problem: you may want to use first parameter as default and the second - as not default.
In this case you need provide first parameter manually or use overloading

```
void method(queue x){
    method(0, x);
}
```

Comment: Hah, was just about to say you can't have two functions that have purely default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ you can have as many default parameters that you want under one conditions:
the parameters that have default values have to come after all other parameters.

when you assign values they will be assigned in the order the parameter are declared in the function prototype.

Comment: @ elyashiv: but according to my knowledge,learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters a method can take all its parameters to be default parameters , why is it that method(queue2); be an error?

Comment: because you are trying to pass a queue to a int type - as a said the assignment is in the order of the parameters.